# How to set constraints for a reusable UIView in Swift with auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to build a reusable `UIView` whose width should equal to its superview in Swift.

Since the size of its superview varies, I think I have to set constraints for it with auto layout.

But I can't figure out how to do it programmatically in Swift.

Here is the code for the reusable subview:

```
import UIKit

class bottomMenu: UIView {

@IBOutlet var bottomMenu: UIView!


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("bottomMenu", owner: self, options: nil)

    bottomMenu.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    //How to make the width of the bottom Menu equal to its superview?

    self.addSubview(self.bottomMenu)
    }

}
```

Can anyone show me how to make it?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a xib for custom UI?

Comment: Yes, I have a xib. I have set the width to 320px.So it can work well when I run it on iPhone 5. But when I change the device to iPhone 6, it cannot match the screen's width . That's why I hope it can work with auto layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can `override didMoveToSuperview()` method in your UIView subclass and add the constraints there:

```
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let views = ["view" : self];
        self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        self.superview?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[view]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.superview?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views))
    }
```

Comment: Won't this make extra constraints each time the view is reused?

Answer (score 0):

Add constraints for element inside. For each element add constraint for top, bottom, left and right. If you have any images that needs to be same size add width and height as well. If you can post the screenshot of the UIView I will add more information and will be able to be more helpful.

Also take a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 if you are new to autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives the loaded view the same height and width as the super view. (not sure what you wanted for height)

```
bottomMenu.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

//Views to add constraints to
let views = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("bottomMenu",bottomMenu))

// Horizontal constraints
let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bottomMenu]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
self.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)

// Vertical constraints
let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[bottomMenu]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
self.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
```

Comment: I removed 'view' from self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints), and it works! thanks

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. I see that you are calling from a UIView subclass and not a UIViewController. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thx! sorry I haven't earned enough reputation to upvote your answer